# Выборка строки RadGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

Как по нажатию клавиши мыши, выбрать всю строку в RadGridView и поместить элементы в List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение :

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        GetRowData(dataGridView1,stringList,e);
    }
```

Метод:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Метод добавляет всю строку в список типа list<string>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGridView">тут должна быть dataGridView </param>
    /// <param name="stringList">ListString</param>
    /// <param name="e">Событие нажатия DataGridViewCellEventArgs </param>
    private void GetRowData(DataGridView dataGridView, List<string> stringList, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       int columsCount = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
        string rowLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < columsCount; i++)
        {
            rowLine +=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
        }
        stringList.Add(rowLine);
    }
```